# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, callstack

I am trying to solve this kata on Codewars: https://www.codewars.com/kata/56e56756404bb1c950000992/train/javascript, and I have a method that I think should be correct, but it throws a RangeError. This is my code:

```
function sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs(pairs){
  return pairs.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    // LCM * GCD = product
    return acc + (curr[0] * curr[1] * (1 - 1 / GCD(curr)))
  }, 0)
}

function GCD(pair) {
  // Euclidean algorithm
  let a = Math.max(...pair);
  let b = Math.min(...pair);
  let r = a % b;
  if (r == 0) {
    return b;
  }
  return GCD([b, r]);
}
```

Where am I going wrong? How else can I implement the Euclidean Algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I get any of the maths stuff here, but skipping zeros seems to stop it from trying to recurse forever.

Anything % 0 will give `NaN` and probably anything % NaN will give `NaN` and NaN == 0 is false, so if you start with a zero value entering GCD there's no way for the recursion to terminate.

```js
function sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs(pairs){
  return pairs.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    // LCM * GCD = product
    if(Math.min(...curr) === 0) return acc; // Skip zeros
    return acc + (curr[0] * curr[1] * (1 - 1 / GCD(curr)))
  }, 0)
}

function GCD(pair) {
  // Euclidean algorithm
  let a = Math.max(...pair);
  let b = Math.min(...pair);
  let r = a % b;
  
  if (r == 0) {
    return b;
  }
  return GCD([b, r]);
}

console.log(sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs([[15,18], [4,5], [12,60]]),840);
console.log(sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs([[1,1], [0,0], [13,91]]),1092);
console.log(sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs([[15,7], [4,5], [19,60]]),0);
console.log(sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs([[20,50], [10,10], [50,20]]),1890);
console.log(sumDifferencesBetweenProductsAndLCMs([]),0);
```